# Getting a list of data by cell length

Tags: google-sheets

I have 1 column in a google spreedsheet (of all countries) and I need to get a list of all countries that are X number of characters long.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A with a header row:

```
=filter(A2:A , len(A2:A)=5 )
```

Change the number to the length you want.

Or, you could put the length in a cell and vary the length by what is in the cell:

```
=filter(A2:A , len(A2:A)=C2 )
```